# Can we plot non-linear data points over a diagonal line in plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, plotly, gnuplot, scatter-plot

I need to plot a column over a straight line irrespective of their values.
For example if I have following data:

| ID | colA | colB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 70 |
| 2 | 30 | -20 |
| 3 | 60 | 60 |
| 4 | 20 | 20 |
| 5 | 10 | -40 |
| 6 | 50 | -10 |
| 7 | 10 | 65 |

I want to have two curves,

curve 1: straight line at 45 degree which has points as 50, 30, 60, 20, 10, 50, 10 on straight for respective ID on x axis.

Curve 2: scatter plot from ColB showing deviation from respective colA entry. Point will be placed below or above the point on the straight line.

Goal is to show the deviation of ColB from ColA, so that I keep on improving the ColB numbers until deviation is 0, and both columns gets on same straight line.

Comment: Why do you add the tag `gnuplot` when you are asking about `plotly`? Do you want a gnuplot solution?

Comment: Do you want the x-values to be in numerical order, or in the order of the ID?

Comment: @DerekO Want x values in order of the ID

Comment: @theozh Wanted the solution in plotly, but if I can get solution in gnuplot, that is also fine as I can make plotly version of it myself.

Comment: @user1660982 if you force x=50 to occupy the first tick mark on the xaxis (ID=1), and x=30 to occupy the second tick mark on the xaxis (ID=2) then the yaxis will need to have y=50 as the first tick of the yaxis, and y=30 as the second tick of the yaxis. but if the yaxis is categorical like the xaxis, then showing deviation doesn't make sense (how do you plot x=50 and y=70 on a chart where both axes are categorical?). if you make both axes categorical in the order of the ID, then deviation from a straight line won't have any meaning

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can plot a straight line by setting the x and y-values to the values in `colA`, then plot the values of colA against colB:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':list(range(1,8)),
    'colA':[50,30,60,20,10,50,10],
    'colB':[70,-20,60,20,-40,-10,65]
})

## make xaxis categorical
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['colA'],
    y=df['colA'],
    mode='lines'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['colA'],
    y=df['colB'],
    mode='markers'
))

x_min, x_max = min(df['colA']), max(df['colA'])
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='array', categoryarray= df['colA'].values, range=[x_min-0.1, x_max+0.1])
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Derek, What does fig.update_xaxes() line do?

Comment: I was trying to set the xaxis to be a categorical array, but I realized it doesn't do anything because all of the values are in the same order as if it were a linear xaxis.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer using **gnuplot**.

It draws black points representing 'colA' data and red points representing 'colA+colB'. In addition, vertical lines connecting the above two points are drawn in gray using the "with vectors" style.

To make the straight line 45 degrees, it matches the scales of the vertical and horizontal axes as follows.

```
set size ratio -1
```

The whole script is here.

```
$DATA << EOD
# ID    colA    colB
1   50  70
2   30  -20
3   60  60
4   20  20
5   10  -40
6   50  -10
7   10  65
EOD

set size ratio -1
set xrange [-40:140]
set yrange [-40:140]
set grid xtics ytics
unset key 

plot x with line lc rgb 'black', \
     $DATA using 2:2:(0):3 with vectors lc rgb 'gray' nohead, \
     $DATA using 2:2 with points pt 7 lc rgb 'black', \
     $DATA using 2:($2+$3) with points pt 7 lc rgb 'red'
```

[image]